# Is there a classifying topos for schemes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, topos-theory

Is there a topos $\mathcal E$ such that, for any sober topological space $X$, the geometric morphisms
$$\mathrm{Sh}\left(\mathcal O\left(X\right)\right)\rightarrow \mathcal E$$
are in correspondance with the schemes whose underlying topological space is $X$?

Comment: Just a comment : this is not true that schemes whose topological space is a single point, are $\operatorname{Spec}k$ for $k$ a field. There are non reduced schemes with this property : $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]/(x^2)$ for example.

Comment: @Roland Thank you! This isn't my area so I thought I might have made a mistake (it turns out that my mistake was thinking that the $0$ ideal is always prime (in fact that's the definition of "integral domain")). The second paragraph is just nonsense now so I'll delete it.

Comment: Interesting question. Any reasonable candidate will be a sub-topos of the big Zariski topos over $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$, which is the classifying topos of local rings. The geometric morphisms from a sober space $X$ to it are the sheaves of local rings on $X$. But now we would have to let the topos of $X$ detect whether an internal local ring comes from a sheaf or not..? (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) Perhaps the condition is that an appropriate internal spectrum is the singleton locale? The naive internal spectrum does not work; I believe it detects the empty or zero-dimensional schemes. This should correspond to the classifying topos of local rings with the property that every element is invertible or nilpotent. Perhaps this can be shown along the lines as in Ingo Blechschmidt's notes https://github.com/iblech/internal-methods where similar things are shown.

Comment: @Ben: I believe the issue is not detecting whether an internal local ring comes from a sheaf (any internal local ring will be, by definition, an object of the topos, therefore a sheaf), but whether the pair $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is locally affine.

Comment: Indeed, you are right, thank you @IngoBlechschmidt I don't know what I was thinking..

Comment: No worries, @Ben! By the way, your comment that the topos would have to be a subtopos of the big Zariski topos was spot on, assuming that Oscar intended the bijection to be induced by pullback of the generic model.

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt My motivation was the question was this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.1415 which shows that sheaves on $X$ can be thought of as continuous functions $X\to\mathrm{Set}$. So I was wondering if other sheaf based notions could be thought of in the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question! No, such a topos $\mathcal{E}$ cannot exist.

Fix your favorite topological space $X$ which cannot be made into a scheme, that is, such that for no local sheaf of rings $\mathcal{O}_X$, the pair $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is a scheme. For instance the reals with their Euclidean topology will do (the only open subspace of $\mathbb{R}^1$ which is a spectral space is the empty one).

Then there shouldn't be any geometric morphism $\mathrm{Sh}(X) \to \mathcal{E}$. However, we can easily construct such as a morphism, for instance as the composition of the unique morphism $\mathrm{Sh}(X) \to \mathrm{Sh}(\mathrm{pt})$ and the morphism $\mathrm{Sh}(\mathrm{pt}) \to \mathcal{E}$ corresponding to any of the many scheme structures on $\mathrm{pt}$.

Comment: Probably [Simon Henry's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2944700/61604) to the related question whether there is a classifying topos of locales can be adapted to the question here, yielding quite a different proof of the non-existence of that topos.